# Attributes mapping in cognito user pool from fb/Google.

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

There's new feature in aws cognito to allow user to sign in through external federation identity providers in user pool.
I followed the steps given the aws Doc.
1) select identity providers
2) attributes  mapping
But when I sign up, fb/ Google account ID don't get map in user pool.
Can someone give me a proper code to do this. I mean how should I map fb/ Google user sign in programmatically in cognito user pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, only the Facebook id, Google sub, and Login with Amazon user_id attributes can be mapped to the [Amazon Cognito](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-attribute-mapping.html) user pools username attribute.

What does your attribute mapping look like?

Comment: so if check other fields(email) it doesn't map? thank you.

Comment: It does map, but not to the username attribute.

Comment: @NavinKhandeparkar I've hit a similar problem and posted a question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547452/how-to-use-federation-from-a-user-pool-not-from-an-identity-pool. 
Are either of you able to answer my question?